# How can I undo last local (not pushed) commit using git-plus?

Tags: git, github

As my question above I want to know how to undo last local (not pushed) commit using **git-plus** package in **Atom** text editor. How can I undo last local commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can not do that with git-plus. But with this simple command :

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

You can undo the last commit.
Pay attention it is a hard reset, so you will loose any pending changes. You can `stash` them before.

Comment: it seems too difficult! at last I use Bracket with Bracket Git it is easier